# Questions on diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra

1. We have "$\lambda \in K$ is an eigenvalue of $A \in M_n(K)$ $\iff \chi_A(\lambda)=\det(\lambda I_n-A)=0$", and this analogue: "Consider an $n$-dimensional $K$-vector space $V$ and $f:V\to V$ a linear operator on $V$. $\lambda \in K$ is an eigenvalue of $f\iff \chi_f(\lambda)=\det(\lambda \mathbf{1}-f)=0$".

The proof of the second statements uses $0=\det(\lambda I_n-A)=\det(\lambda \mathbf{1} -f)$ (with $A$ the matrix representation of $f$), but I can't really see where the equality come from.

2. > $A\in M_n(K)$ is diagonalizable if and only if there exists a matrix $P\in GL_n(K)$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix.

This is the proof:

$\Rightarrow$:Consider the standard basis $\mathcal{B}$ for $K^n$. Suppose that $A$ (and therefor $L_A$) is diagonalizable. Then there is a basis $\mathcal{B'}=\{b_1,\dots,b_n\}$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$. Define $P$, the transition matrix from $\mathcal{B}$ to $\mathcal{B'}$; **Then $L_{P^{-1}AP}$ maps $b_i$ to $\lambda_i b_i$. Conclusion: $P^{-1}AP = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1\dots,\lambda_n)$**.

$\Leftarrow$: Suppose there is a $P \in GL_n(K)$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal, and consider the basis $\mathcal{B'} = \{Pe_1,\dots,Pe_n\}$ of $K^n$. **It is clear that the matrix of $L_A$ $(A_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B}})$ will be the diagonal matrix $P^{-1}AP$.**

I don't understand the sentences that are put in bold. Can someone help me see the logic behind it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Since $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, there is a non-zero vector $v$ such that $Av=\lambda v$. But$$Av=\lambda v\iff(\lambda\operatorname{Id}-A).v=0\implies\det(\lambda\operatorname{Id}-A)=0.$$
2. If $\mathcal{B}=\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$, then the entries of the $i$<sup>th</sup> column of $P$ are the coordinates of $b_i$ with respect to $\mathcal B$. So, $(AP).e_i=A.b_i=\lambda_ib_i$. On the other hand, $P^{-1}.b_i=e_i$, and so $(P^{-1}AP).e_i=\lambda_ie_i$. And if $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal, then $(P^{-1}AP)e_i=\lambda_ie_i$. But$$(P^{-1}AP)e_i=\lambda_ie_i\iff A.(Pe_i)=\lambda_i(Pe_i).$$So, yes, the matrix $L_A$ with respect to $\{Pe_1,\ldots,Pe_n\}$ will be diagonal.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just two quick questions: 1) I see why $\det(\lambda I_n - A) = 0$, but why is $\det(\lambda I_n - A) =  \det(\lambda \mathbf{1} - f)$? 2)  You say that $(P^{-1} A P)\cdot e_i = \lambda_i e_i $, does this also hold for the basis elements $b_i$ in $\mathcal{B'}$?

Comment: 1) $\mathbf{1}$ means $\operatorname{Id}$. 2) There are no $b_i$'s in this part of the proof.